# built in geomspace in julia

Tags: numpy, julia

In NumPy, there is a function for returning a logarithmically spaced range of `n` points between two numbers `begin` and `end`.
In Julia you could define something like this:

```
10 .^(range(log10(begin), log10(end), n)
```

but is there a built-in function like this?

Answer (score 4):

I found some related questions here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/lazy-logspace-object/70091 and https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-do-logspace-in-julia-v-1-0-x/17452.

Basically, there are no built-in short hands for logspace, but you can implement a similar function using `Iterators`.

```
logspace(start, last, count) = Iterators.map(exp10, range(log10(start), log10(last), count))
```

Comment: Should be noted that this doesn't support indexing, so it's not a drop-in replacement for the usual `range` which creates an `AbstractRange`. It looks like progress is being made towards adding `LogRange` to julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/39071

Comment: Maybe also worth noting that e.g. `collect(logspace(1/64, 64, 7))` does not hit either endpoint exactly. The built-in `logrange` guarantees that both ends are exact, and (like some AbstractRanges) uses high-precision numbers to calculate intermediate points.

Answer (score 0):

Julia 1.11 finally has a built-in `logrange` function which, as requested above. On earlier versions of Julia, it's available from the package Compat.jl:

```
julia> using Compat

julia> logrange(1/4, 16, length=5)
5-element Compat.LogRange{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}:
  0.25
  0.7071067811865476
  2.0
  5.656854249492381
 16.0
```

This is similar to `numpy.geomspace` in Python. But like Julia's `range` or `LinRange`, it returns a special lazy vector type which allows random access, without allocating all space for all the values.